# Testcafe - Typing user name and password into Native Dialog

Tags: authentication, testing, automation, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm using Testcafe to test a corporate web solution.

One of the ways we authenticate is Windows authentication.
If this type of authentication is enabled, on the page load, a native dialog appears and I have to type in user name and password and click Sign In, or Cancel.

I couldn't find an explanation or example of this in TestCafe.

Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the approach described in the [HTTP Authentication](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/http-authentication.html) topic for this purpose.